# I forgot 'git push'

Tags: github, push, git-commit, git-push

I have several commits on my branch but I forgot to push them. Currently, those changes are in another computer so I wonder if there is a way to reach that commits without pushing.

Comment: Is your computer accessible through the web? If it isn't, there is nothing you could do but to go get it...

Comment: If you didn’t push changes from your local computer to the remote repository, they’re stuck on that local computer. Only workaround is if you happen to backup your local repositories on that computer to a cloud service (or somehow connect to your computer remotely - as mentioned above).

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to reach the computer right now. So nothing possible I guess.

Comment: You could have used `git bundle` to store the state of the repository offline on a disk or something, but I'm guessing you didn't do that. You could work on another part of the programme, then merge when you have access to the computer.

Comment: No, I didnt. thanks anyway, Ill keep it in my mind